# RGBDSLAM on turtlebot

Tags: slam, navigation, turtlebot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How does one use the camera on turtlebot to rgbdslam on another workstation?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/30881/rgbdslam-on-turtlebot/) by [allenh1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1086/allenh1/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3055 on 2012-03-30

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can just set the point-cloud topic in RGBDSLAM's launch file to an empty string. It will do the reprojection then by itself.

---

Originally posted by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) with karma: 6468 on 2012-04-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0